# Vue 2 Laravel 5.3 Vue-router 2 Proper way to set up Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-router

Just want to set up a simple redirection upon click on something. Not sure how to use vue-router to do such. Please find my codes below:

app.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/' },
    { path: '/product', redirect: '/product' }
  ]
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Navbar-main.vue

```
<template>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-left navbar-btn" @click.prevent="goToHome()" @mouseover.prevent="hoverIcon('home')" @mouseleave.prevent="hoverIcon('')">
      <div class="nav-link nav-main" :class="[{ 'navbar-home-hover' : hovered == 'home' },{ 'navbar-home' : hovered !== 'home' }]">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-left navbar-btn" @click.prevent="goToProduct()" @mouseover.prevent="hoverIcon('product')" @mouseleave.prevent="hoverIcon('')">
      <div class="nav-link nav-main" :class="[{ 'navbar-product-hover' : hovered == 'product' },{ 'navbar-product' : hovered !== 'product' }]">Product</div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-left navbar-btn" @mouseover.prevent="hoverIcon('blog')" @mouseleave.prevent="hoverIcon('')">
      <div class="nav-link nav-main" :class="[{ 'navbar-blog-hover' : hovered == 'blog' },{ 'navbar-blog' : hovered !== 'blog' }]">Blog</div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item-left navbar-btn" @mouseover.prevent="hoverIcon('mktInfo')" @mouseleave.prevent="hoverIcon('')">
      <div class="nav-link nav-main" :class="[{ 'navbar-mktInfo-hover' : hovered == 'mktInfo' },{ 'navbar-mktInfo' : hovered !== 'mktInfo' }]">Market Info</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return{
        hovered: '',
      }
    },
    methods:{
        hoverIcon(input){
            var vm = this
            vm.hovered = input
        },
        goToHome(){
            this.$router.push('/');
        },
        goToProduct(){
            this.$router.push('/product');
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

error upon click Home

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

EDIT#1 (on app.js)

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter); //this is deleted

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/' },
    { path: '/product', redirect: '/product' }
  ]
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router //this is added in this edit
});
```

Comment: is there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't injecting your router into your app, hence it being 'undefined'

To inject the router make following changes in the Vue app in **app.js**:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router // inject the router
});
```

After that you can use `this.$router` throughout the app.

---

**Other approach:**

You have to import `router` from `app.js` like following:

import router from './path/to/app

and after that you can simply  use:

```
router.push
```

Comment: thanks for your response @saurabh, I have tried your first suggestion, but console log returns errors
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.exec (<anonymous>)
    at RegExp.[Symbol.match] (native)
    at String.match (native)

Comment: Is there meaningless/excessive code that I added into my app.js?

Comment: @warmjaijai I think `Vue.use(VueRouter);` is not needed now,  check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/xgrjzsup/).

Comment: Thanks @saurabh, I made the edit as you said (please refer to my question) and the Maximum call error gone. However the old error still here when I click Home: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: I also try to use router-link in my Navbar-main.vue too but it says i didn't register.

Comment: any clue still?